# JS: Getting location.href from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of form objects and I have like to get the url in the form objects if it met a condition.  I tried like below:

```
    <div
      onClick={() =>
        (location.href = `${_.filter(forms, function (form) {
          console.log('url 84390')
          console.log(row.form_id)
          console.log(form.id)
          if (form.id === row.form_id) {
            console.log(form.formUrl). //form.formUrl is correctly printed out  /staff/forms/xgcba
            return form.formUrl
          }
        })}`)
      }
    >
      {row.form_id}
    </div>
```

However, I got the error as below:

```
No route matches [GET] "/staff/[object%20Object]"
```

I think form.formUrl is not correctly assigned to location.href.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It works as below.

```
 const handleUrl = (row) => {
    forms.map((form) => {
      if (form.id === row.form_id) {
        location.href = form.formUrl
      }
    })
  }
```